# C: Most recent maximum array value

Tags: c, arrays, max

In an array of temperatures, each day for a whole month:

```
int april[31];
    int days;
    int i=0, maxpos, max;

    printf("How many days are in this month?\n");
    scanf("%d", &days);

    if (days < 0)
       printf("Unreceivable number of days\n");
    else{

         for(i=0; i <= days-1; i++)
         {
             printf("Day %d: Give today's temperature: \n", i+1);
             scanf("%d", &april[i]);
         }

         for(i=0; i <= days-1; i++)
             printf("%Day %d  = %d\n", i+1, april[i]);  

         maxpos=0; 
         max = april[0];   

         for(i=0; i <= days-1; i++)
         {
              if (april[i] > max)
              {
                 max = april[i];
                 maxpos = i;
              }
         }  

         printf("The maximum temperature of the month is %d on Day %d of the month\n", max, maxpos+1);

     }
```

the programme has to print out the maximum temperature and the day that happened, like:

```
The maximum temperature is 42 on Day 2 of the month
```

But, what if two days of the month have the same temperature? 
I guess the screen will show the first/older temperature:

```
Day 1 = 23
Day 2 = 33
Day 3 = 33
Day 4 = 30
Day 5 = 33
```

in this case, Day 2.

How can I make it print the latest, most recent maximum temperature (Day 5 in the example above)?

Comment: Note, April has 30 days, not 31. Using `int month[31];` would be less confusing.

Comment: As a point of style, instead of `for(i=0; i<=days-1; i++)` please code as `for(i=0; i<days; i++)`. It's clearer, and if you continue your way, eventually you'll fall into a hole when you have `unsigned days = 0;` which can easily happen when analysing data.

Comment: I'm just experimenting, nothing serious about this code, but thank you for your observation, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your code

`if(april[i]>max)`

must be changed to

`if(april[i]>=max)`

the **reason** being that, in first case once max value gets assigned by entering the `if` statement, once again when same value is repeated it wont enter  the if block as max > max is false but in second case as max>=max is true, compiler would enter the if block and update its value.

Comment: Just a **tip**: You can put the if block in the above for loop which is used to print the day and its temperature @Coursal

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
if (april[i] >= max)
```

which will save the position if temp equals current maximum, so you will have last day with that temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write

```
if (april[i] >= max) instead of if (april[i] > max)
```

this will find the maximum and also the recent one i mean the last one as it is checking whether the coming index value is same or bigger than the previous one if so just update the max.